# Enum or dictionary for inmemory parameter

Tags: c#, enum, dictionary

I have a table UserItems {ID, UserID, ItemID}

Items must be in RAM (not in db table).

What is better for this? As enum with attributes or as dictionary of items?:

```
enum Items
{
    [InternalParam("x432", 34)]
    Red = 1,
    [InternalParam("x431", 12)]
    Green = 2,
    [InternalParam("x438", 54)]
    White = 3
}
```

OR

```
enum ItemsIds {Red=1, Green=2, White=3}
Dictionary<ItemsIds, Item> Items = new Dictionary(){
    {Red, new Item("x432", 34)},
    {Green, new Item("x431", 12)},
    {White, new Item("x438", 54)},
}
```

Comment: Basically, it's a compromise between efficiency and flexibility. A raw enum has best efficiency but can't easely be altered at runtime, a dictionary based consumes slightly more but can be altered at runtime easely ...and a small DB lives in RAM anyway, has some overhead, but provides lots of tools and features on top.

Comment: this data is fixed and readonly

Comment: If the data is fixed and read-only, an enum is always preferable, as you can maintain the code more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain that the ids are not going to change and that the ids are and will be linear, the first would be preferable, since you can simply grab the enum by using the id as an ordinal.

Though in my humble opinion, you would be doing yourself a favor to assume that ids *can* change if you're having to lookup the enum given its item id.  My reasoning is like this:  Suppose your client is having a problem with the current version of your program, and in it, you have 15 items and therefore 15 enums for each id.  The only way to fix the problem is to revert to an earlier version which just so happens to use *14* items and *14* enums.  *Best case scenario*, you simply can't, otherwise you risk to read item with id 15 from the database and your program doesn't *have* the enum for it.

Of course the worst case scenario is actually updating the program to the earlier version and creating a lot of unexpected hassle.  Bottom line:  treat items as enum *or* persisted database data, but NOT BOTH.

If you can't eliminate the need to use item ids coming from the database, you shouldn't be using enums, yes *even* if you don't think they'll change and yes *even* if they're only 15 objects you can hold in memory.  Go the extra mile.  You can load it on program start and nobody will be the wiser.